# What's the best way to create a popover for every single word in a paragraph on dblclick? (HTML/CSS/Bootstrap4/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create something similar to Kindle's Word Wise and MacOS's Dictionary feature for a class. My goal is to allow the user double click on a word and view its definition. I'm very new to front end programming so I've been having a lot of trouble. I tried my best to research and try different methods to attain my desired end result, but I can't seem to get it to work.

So basically, every time a user double clicks on a word, a popover should appear with its definition. I wanted to find a way to create popovers on a click event, rather than hard coding in the popover attribute for every word.

Edit: Explaining a little more thoroughly...so if this is an example of how to add a popover on an element:

```
<a href="#" data-container="body" 
data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus 
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
Popover on top
</a>
```

...Is there a way to do this for every single word without having to add the individual element and attributes for each word?

This is the code I have so far.

```
function getSelectedText(){
    var selectedText = '';
        if (window.getSelection)
               selectedText = window.getSelection();
return selectedText;
}


$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(function () {
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

$('#selectable').on("dblclick", function () {
$('.selection').text(getSelectedText());
$('.is-selected').text(getSelectedText() != "");
    });

$('#selectable').on('click',function (e) {
 var text= getSelectedText();
 $( '#selectable:contains(text)' ).replaceWith('<span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="testing popover>' + text +'</span>')
});
});
```

Comment: So is your question how to use a [modal](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)?  Or is it how to make a request that fetches the definition?

Comment: @PatrickQ My question is how can I make every single word have a bootstrap popover without having to add the attribute in for every single word within a div.

Comment: Is your content populated by PHP or is it static/hard-coded HTML?

Comment: @PatrickQ It's on a php file... the header and footer are php, but the body, majority of the content, is hard-coded html.

Comment: Well, then if your definition of a "word" is text delimited by a space, then I'd say have a look at the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function.  Run that against your block of text, passing a space as the delimiter.  Then loop over the resulting array, wrapping each "word" with the markup required to add the tooltip, appending to a new string (that will become the new block of content) as you go.